# Cannot click on a button when using watir webdriver with IE8 but works for Firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

My watir-webdriver acceptance tests run successfully when I use Firefox v35.01. However when I swap the browser to IE8, the first step which involves clicking on the login button fails with the following error:

```
Unable to find element with xpath == .//button[contains(concat(' ', @
class, ' '), '  x-btn-text login ')] | .//input[contains(concat(' ',      @class, ' '
), '  x-btn-text login ') and (translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abc
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='button' or translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
Z','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='reset' or translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
TUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='submit' or translate(@type,'ABCDEFGHIJKL
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='image')] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDocumentError)
```

The code for the button is

```
td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button class=" x-btn-text login" id="ext-gen64" type="button">Login</button></em>
```

The code I am using to click on the button is :

```
@browser.button(:class => " x-btn-text login").when_present.click
```

I am running

Environment is: Windows 7 32 bit,IE8 v8.0.7601, Firefox v35, Ruby 1.9.3, Selenium-webdriver (v2.44) and Watir-webdriver (v0.66)

Comment: Any chance the page you are testing is publicly available? With the HTML and code given, IE8 seemed to work fine for me. Though I was using Selenium-Webdriver v2.45 (with the matching IEDriverServer version).

Comment: Hi @JustinKo I don't believe this page would be publicly available as it is an internal app for the company I work at but I will double check.  My IEDriverServer version is v2.25.3.0. Is there a link I can find out which IEDriverServer version matches with which Selenium-Webdriver version?

Comment: I've tried  I was using Selenium-Webdriver v2.44 with the matching IEDriverServer version and still getting the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

if the ID value is consistent you might want to try using that to select the button.  In valid HTML id values will be unique on a page, and no more than one element on the page (excluding stuff inside a frame) can have the same ID.

Also double-check if you have not already that the HTML served up to IE8 is the same as that for Firefox.

IE8 has only rudimentary support for HTML 5.  it [scores](https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html) a mere 33 compared to 336 for IE11 or 450+ for current Firefox and Chrome.  So potentially the site might be 'downshifting' if it detects IE8 and using different code in order to be compatible with that 6 year old clunker of a browser

Comment: Hi Chuck thanks for the ideas! I had already tried using the ID to select the button and got the same results. However your other suggestion about checking what HTML is served up to IE8 sounds like it could be the culprit. I had tried to look at the HTML using the developer tools in IE (clicking on F12) but for some reason no HTML tags load and I just get some text saying `Loading......`but nothing loads and it just sits there. I also tried installing the IE developer toolbar but get a similar result with no HTML loading.

Comment: Perhaps the above is another symptom of my problem or maybe the cause of it. I'm thinking that the IE8 browser I'm using is a customized one that is used in our standard operating environment at work. I am considering uninstalling it and maybe re-installing a version from the Microsoft site if I can find it and then give it another go. Has anyone else experienced this issue with IE developer tools not loading HTML for a site?

Comment: Looks like someone has had a similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661164/ie8-developer-tools-not-displaying-style-info) My app uses ExtJS so worth trying it out maybe

Comment: I recently had an issue with the IE developer tool not loading the HTML. It turned out that we were incorrectly closing some of the elements. While Chrome/Firefox gracefully handled and interpreted the HTML, IE8 repeated the incorrect HTML over and over until the HTML became too massive for the developer tool to handle. I think stripping down your page to the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem might help.

Comment: I tried migrating my automated tests to an older VM test environment running Windows 2003 server, IE8 v8.0.6001, selenium- webdriver v2.31 and IEDriverServer version v2.25.3  In this environment the developer tools in IE loaded the HTML successfully and my automated test for clicking on the login button worked. I wish I had a more conclusive explanation but it would appear the Windows 7 VM image( containing IE8 v8.0.7601) I was using for testing is somewhat corrupted. Thanks again for your comments and suggestions.